# Highcharts two datetime xAxis chart with same ticks interval

Tags: charts, highcharts

I two days think about problem, but i don't know make chart with two normalized datetime xAxis.

1. I Tried use linkedTo and normalize data arrays (but this hard overkill).
2. linkedTo showing only overlapped data.
3. Without linkedTo and normalization arrays, ticks showed as async like this

Help me, please

[What make chart like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgg2L.png)

```js
$('#container').highcharts({
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth:0  
    },
    xAxis: [
      {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        type: 'datetime',
        lineColor: '#ff9c00'
      },
      {
        type: 'datetime',
        opposite: true,
        lineColor: '#FF6B6B'
      }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            "name": "first",
            "data": [
                [
                    1479164400000,
                    7323
                ],
                [
                    1479160800000,
                    6204
                ],
                [
                    1479157200000,
                    3561
                ],
                [
                    1479153600000,
                    9706
                ],
                [
                    1479150000000,
                    2539
                ],
                [
                    1479146400000,
                    4570
                ],
                [
                    1479142800000,
                    4187
                ],
                [
                    1479139200000,
                    3631
                ],
                [
                    1479135600000,
                    7512
                ],
                [
                    1479132000000,
                    2456
                ],
                [
                    1479128400000,
                    6983
                ],
                [
                    1479124800000,
                    3511
                ],
                [
                    1479121200000,
                    2765
                ],
                [
                    1479117600000,
                    3401
                ],
                [
                    1479114000000,
                    2565
                ],
                [
                    1479110400000,
                    4425
                ],
                [
                    1479106800000,
                    4592
                ],
                [
                    1479103200000,
                    4328
                ],
                [
                    1479099600000,
                    2694
                ],
                [
                    1479096000000,
                    2787
                ],
                [
                    1479092400000,
                    11633
                ],
                [
                    1479088800000,
                    3311
                ],
                [
                    1479085200000,
                    2839
                ],
                [
                    1479081600000,
                    12620
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "second",
            "data": [
                [
                    1479250800000,
                    22730
                ],
                [
                    1479247200000,
                    10695
                ],
                [
                    1479243600000,
                    12017
                ],
                [
                    1479240000000,
                    12110
                ],
                [
                    1479236400000,
                    9689
                ],
                [
                    1479232800000,
                    4288
                ],
                [
                    1479229200000,
                    3702
                ],
                [
                    1479225600000,
                    5575
                ],
                [
                    1479222000000,
                    5694
                ],
                [
                    1479218400000,
                    3098
                ],
                [
                    1479214800000,
                    9885
                ],
                [
                    1479211200000,
                    6587
                ],
                [
                    1479207600000,
                    3028
                ],
                [
                    1479204000000,
                    3281
                ],
                [
                    1479200400000,
                    12577
                ],
                [
                    1479196800000,
                    3886
                ],
                [
                    1479193200000,
                    4014
                ],
                [
                    1479189600000,
                    6553
                ],
                [
                    1479186000000,
                    2041
                ],
                [
                    1479182400000,
                    4056
                ],
                [
                    1479178800000,
                    4223
                ],
                [
                    1479175200000,
                    4920
                ],
                [
                    1479171600000,
                    5432
                ],
                [
                    1479168000000,
                    7857
                ],
                [
                    1479164400000,
                    7323
                ],
                [
                    1479160800000,
                    6204
                ],
                [
                    1479157200000,
                    3561
                ],
                [
                    1479153600000,
                    9706
                ],
                [
                    1479150000000,
                    2539
                ],
                [
                    1479146400000,
                    4570
                ],
                [
                    1479142800000,
                    4187
                ],
                [
                    1479139200000,
                    3631
                ],
                [
                    1479135600000,
                    7512
                ],
                [
                    1479132000000,
                    2456
                ],
                [
                    1479128400000,
                    6983
                ],
                [
                    1479124800000,
                    3511
                ],
                [
                    1479121200000,
                    2765
                ],
                [
                    1479117600000,
                    3401
                ],
                [
                    1479114000000,
                    2565
                ],
                [
                    1479110400000,
                    4425
                ],
                [
                    1479106800000,
                    4592
                ],
                [
                    1479103200000,
                    4328
                ],
                [
                    1479099600000,
                    2694
                ],
                [
                    1479096000000,
                    2787
                ],
                [
                    1479092400000,
                    11633
                ],
                [
                    1479088800000,
                    3311
                ],
                [
                    1479085200000,
                    2839
                ],
                [
                    1479081600000,
                    12620
                ]
            ],
            "xAxis": 1,
            "dashStyle": "shortdot"
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 1024px;
    max-width: 1024px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You have to control tick positions in both axis. In the example you provided, it is enough to set axis.endOnTick to true. With different chart's width it might be not sufficient though. https://jsfiddle.net/wtaq5jcL/

Comment: @morganfree thanks, but yes, not sufficient if different one day and more days (as in example). I'm looking way to fix it

Comment: check my answer, should be bulletproof now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is as follows:

1. Grab the bottom axis ticks values
2. Map the values to pixels
3. Map the pixels to top axis values
4. Set the values to top axis ticks

All the calculation can be done in [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner).

```
tickPositioner: function() {
  var axisTop = this,
    axisBottom = this.chart.xAxis[0],
    ticksBottom = axisBottom.tickPositions;

  var ticksTop = ticksBottom.map(function(tickValue) {
    return axisTop.toValue(axisBottom.toPixels(tickValue));
  });

  return ticksTop;
},
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/439adgpa/

After setting tick positions in tick positioner, you have to manually set the correct format or use it from the bottom axis ticks.

```
labels: {
  format: '{value:%H:%M}'
}
```

or

```
ticksTop.info = ticksBottom.info;
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/439adgpa/1/

Comment: Good workaround :) It's first part, also need points sync. But anyway, i suggested feature request, because need same, only for pointsInterval :)

Answer (score 0):

Use stacked series over each other. yAxis stacked and numbered as 0,1,2.
[Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4b33pvc2/15/)

```
               {
                      name : 'First',
                      data :data for first, 
                      zIndex : 1,
                      lineWidth:3,
                      color:'red',
                      yAxis: 0 ,
                      marker : {
                          enabled : false

                      } 
                  }, {
                      name : 'second',
                      data : data for second, 
                      lineWidth:3,
                      zIndex : 1,
                      yAxis: 1 ,
                      color:'#BE6230',
                      marker : {
                          enabled : false

                      } 
                  }
```

Comment: We need chart on same yAxis (on same plane). For comparing series on date range (f.ex. current week and previous week). Stacked not gives make this.